# Form I-130 Beneficiary entry information

Tags: immigration

I am a green card holder and filing form I-130 for my wife. My wife came to US on student visa (F1) and got her H1B approved. I am stuck at question 46 regarding beneficiary entry information. Question 46a says "He or She arrived as a (Class Of Admission)".

Do I have to refer her first ever entry to US or the most recent entry?

Also for question 46b, 46c and 46d, do I get information from here first I-94 or the most recent I-94, because when she came on student visa date of expiration was "D/S" and now it has changed to her H1B expiration date.

Answer (score 2):

They want to know about her current I-94, which is the most recent I-94.  For the arrival question, they want to know about her most recent arrival.

(Her D/S admission is no longer valid because D/S means "duration of status," and she no longer has F-1 status.)

See also [Which Arrival Date do I enter for my spouse's “Date Arrived” on form I-130 Petition for Alien Relative?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/7521/333) over at [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com).